# Working with 32 bit TIFFs in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, tiff

I am trying to import a 32 bit TIFF into my program.  Since the tiff is multi page I am importing it as an image and then using a stream to make it into a Bitmap.  This works perfectly with 8 bit multipage tiffs, but with 32 bit images it spits out the right number of images with the right dimensions, but as an 8 bit image with every pixel being white.  This issues appears to be with the input as I've tried the code with the image before the stream and it's still white. Here is my code:

```
System.Drawing.Image sampleTiffImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
//this line is probably the one causing the issue

int pageCount = sampleTiffImage.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page);

for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum < pageCount; pageNum++)
{
    sampleTiffImage.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, pageNum);
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        sampleTiffImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        using (Bitmap myBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(memStream))
        {
            //I make other stuff happen here but I have this in for display/debugging.
            myBitmap.Save(@"Save Location" + pageNum + ".bmp");

        }
    }
}
```